# Use a function's argument as a selector in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, arguments

In jQuery, is it possible to use an argument's function as a selector.

I have been attempting something like this but to no avail...

```
function myFunction ( myArgument) {

    $('#'+myArgument).hide();

}

myFunction ( elementOne );
```

Basically when I fire the function with the argument `elementOne` I want to be able to select that element (and then eg, hide it).

Is there a way to do this?

Much thanks in advance!

Comment: That will work, if you have an element with an ID of the value of `elementOne`. If `elementOne` is not a string, you're doing something wrong. Perhaps show the actual code?

Comment: This should work. Are you sure myArgument is a string and the resulting #myArgumentValue exists in your document?

Comment: The problem, it seems, is that `elementOne` was not a variable's value. If I added `var currentElement = 'elementOne'` it worked. I wasn't aware that was necessary...

Answer (score 3):

Simple type test - if you pass a jQuery selector as a string this will hide that, else it will treat it as a jQuery object.

Now with added "make sure it exists" goodness :)

```
if (typeof myArgument === 'string') // eg. myFunction('#something')
  myArgument = $(myArgument);
// else: assume $('#something')
myArgument.length && myArgument.hide();
```